# How can I select only newest entries?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have table like this:

```
IST | FILEDATE  | DATE                | ...
1   | 2013-2014 | 27.03.2015 10:20:47 | ...
2   | 2013-2014 | 27.03.2015 10:20:47 | ...
3   | 2013-2014 | 27.03.2015 10:20:47 | ...
1   | 2013-2014 | 28.03.2015 11:20:47 | ...
2   | 2013-2014 | 28.03.2015 11:20:47 | ...
3   | 2013-2014 | 28.03.2015 11:20:47 | ...
1   | 2014-2015 | 29.03.2015 12:20:47 | ...
2   | 2014-2015 | 29.03.2015 12:20:47 | ...
3   | 2014-2015 | 29.03.2015 12:20:47 | ...
...
```

I need to select newest(with date value) entry of all IST, like this:

```
IST | FILEDATE  | DATE                | ...
1   | 2014-2015 | 29.03.2015 11:20:47 | ...
2   | 2014-2015 | 29.03.2015 11:20:47 | ...
3   | 2014-2015 | 29.03.2015 11:20:47 | ...
```

I tried `order by` and `rownum=1`, but its working for just single IST.

How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a typical scenario where analytical functions (aka windowing functions) are really helpful:

```
with v_data(ist, filedate, entry_date) as (
  select 1, '2013-2014', to_date('27.03.2015 10:20:47','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
  select 2, '2013-2014', to_date('27.03.2015 10:20:47','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
  select 3, '2013-2014', to_date('27.03.2015 10:20:47','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
  select 1, '2013-2014', to_date('28.03.2015 11:20:47','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
  select 2, '2013-2014', to_date('28.03.2015 11:20:47','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
  select 3, '2013-2014', to_date('28.03.2015 11:20:47','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
  select 1, '2014-2015', to_date('29.03.2015 12:20:47','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
  select 2, '2014-2015', to_date('29.03.2015 12:20:47','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all 
  select 3, '2014-2015', to_date('29.03.2015 12:20:47','DD.MM.YYYY hh24:mi:ss') from dual)
select * from (
  select 
     v1.*, 
     row_number() over (partition by ist order by entry_date desc) as rn
  from v_data v1
) 
where rn=1
```

This solution

- computes an ordering per group using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytical function
- removes everything but the newest entry per group with `WHERE rn = 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can first group the result:

```
select ist, max(date) date
from   table
group
by     ist
```

Then you can combine that result with a `select` to get all matching lines:

```
select master.*
from   table master
join
( select ist, max(date) date
  from   table
  group
  by     ist
) filter
on     master.ist  = filter.ist
and    master.date = filter.date
```

Comment: Thank you. `Getting error ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis.`

Comment: Did you replace `table` with your actual table name?

Comment: Oh sorry. Forgot to replace second "table". Its working for me but I have same entries, its show same last entries too. How can I use distinct for this?

Comment: Place `distinct` after the first `select`.

Comment: `Getting error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB`

Comment: @Ric You can't use `DISTINCT` or  `GROUP BY` with a CLOB column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to find ist's that have no newer row in table:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.ist = t1.ist
                    and t2.date > t1.date)*
```